# importing CSV data into MongoDB using python

Tags: json, mongodb, csv, ubuntu

I'm trying to import the following csv file into mongoDB, so I can run a mapreduce on the data in mongo.

https://www.kaggle.com/jessevent/all-crypto-currencies

MongoDB is running on Ubuntu 16.04, with a collection called myCrypto, i've tried the following command and get the error below.

mongoimport --db myCrypto --type csv --headerline --file > /home/john/Documents/crypto-markets.csv

2018-10-15T17:44:40.344+0100    error parsing command line options: expected argument for flag `--file'

Comment: Looks like a typo: you have a `>` following `--file`.

Comment: Thanks David, I can't mark this as the answer, as i have downloaded and installed compass, but it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David mentioned you have a syntax error in your command. The easiest way to achieve what you're after is to use [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) and just imprt through the GUI. (as shown below):

[image]

Then just select the CSV option to import and upload the file to your collection:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! now I just need to figure how to mapreduce it. Any help  appreciated.

Comment: I am fairly certain that will have to be done through the terminal. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/ should give you a start on how to achieve this. An easier tutorial might be: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_map_reduce.htm

Comment: I am using MongoDB compass on a MacOS and I don't get the option of Collection>Import data on my machine